# How to access storage items using polkadot js, javascript playground

Tags: polkadot-js, storage, api, substrate-node-template

As when i try to to do api.query.templatemodule.get_something() it shows errors in the console

Comment: please share a screenshot or extract of the errors, and the version of substrate, substrate-template, or substrate-parachain-template, polkadot.js apps, and polkadot.js api that you're are using

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 3):

Probably the error here is due to Rust doing things with `snake_case`/`UpperCase`, and JavaScript doing things with `camelCase`.

I would never expect that the Polkadot JS API would expose a function which is not `camelCase`, so probably what you want is:

```
api.query.templatemodule.getSomething()
```

This should work fine assuming your storage is named the same thing:

```
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type GetSomething<T: Config> = StorageValue<_, u64, ValueQuery>;
```